# Python FTP server download Latest File with specific keywords in filename

Tags: python, ftp

I want to download the most recent file from FTP server with python. I am able to connect to the server and download all the files in a particular directory but I do not know how to find the most recent file with the specific keyword in the subject.

Following is the code i am using. But it returns all the files with *.png keyname. I do not know how to apply os.path.getctime here to get the latest file.Thats all the help i wanted.

```
        import ftplib
        import os

        ftp = ftplib.FTP('test.rebex.net', 'demo','password')
        ftp.retrlines('LIST')

        ftp.cwd("/pub")

        ftp.retrlines('LIST')

        ftp.cwd("example")

        ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        filematch='*.png'
        target_dir='C:/Users/muzamal.pervez/Desktop/OPD Claims'
        for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
            target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename))
            with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle:
                    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write)
```

Comment: You cant ask questions like write a code and give in SOF. You should try writing code first with your efforts first and then if you are unable to find the reason why your code is not getting executed. You should post that code and ppl here will try to correct it. Its Stack Overflow policy

Comment: There are several flaws in your question. First SO is not a code writing service (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Second, what is a subject in terms of FTP? There are files, but no subject? 
To download the most recent file you have to get the attributes from every file and parse it. It would be better to name the files with a specific format, or move them, when you are done downloading them.

Comment: I think my message was meant in wrong way. I apologize for that. I am updating the code i have done so far. I am doing it on public FTP server.  I am attaching the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolved.

```
    import ftplib
    import os
    import time
    from dateutil import parser

    ftp = ftplib.FTP('test.rebex.net', 'demo','password')
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')

    ftp.cwd("pub")
    ftp.cwd("example")
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')

    names = ftp.nlst()
    final_names= [line for line in names if 'client' in line]

    latest_time = None
    latest_name = None

    for name in final_names:
        time = ftp.sendcmd("MDTM " + name)
        if (latest_time is None) or (time > latest_time):
            latest_name = name
            latest_time = time

    print(latest_name)
    file = open(latest_name, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ latest_name, file.write)
```

Comment: this is great and works perfectly for me. The loops make it slow to do batch tasks. It will be even more awesome if you can share an even faster solution maybe... But Thanks!!